# Entity Framework 6 - How can I view the SQL that will be generated for an insert before calling SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In Entity Framework 6, is it possible to view the SQL that will be executed for an **insert** *before* calling SaveChanges?

```
using (var db = new StuffEntities()){
    db.Things.Add(new Thing({...});
    //can I get the SQL insert statement at this point?
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I'm familiar with how to get the generated SQL for a **query** before execution like so:

```
var query = db.Thing.Where(x => x.ID == 9);
Console.WriteLine(query.ToString());
//this prints the SQL select statement
```

The query returns an IQueryable<> whereas an insert returns a DbSet and calling ToString on a DbSet just prints the standard object name.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Another option (if I understand your question correctly), would be to use an [`IDbCommandInterceptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn469464) implementation, which seemingly allows you to inspect SQL commands before they are executed (I hedge my words as I have not used this myself).

Something like this:

```
public class CommandInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    public void NonQueryExecuting(
        DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        // do whatever with command.CommandText
    }
}
```

Register it using the `DBInterception` class available in EF in your context static constructor:

```
static StuffEntities()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<StuffEntities>(null); // or however you have it
    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterception.Add(new CommandInterceptor());
}
```

Comment: It works! You just have to set interceptionContext.Result and it will stop the database IO. Thanks!

Comment: is DbInterception not DbInterceptor

Comment: @Sven Grosen, can you give an working example or link? Bcoz I tried your way but not working as I have same issue. I might be missing something.

Comment: @VishwajeetKulkarni As I stated in my answer, I've never used this myself, so I can't provide a working example. Lots of other people have seemingly made it work based on feedback, double-check your implementation. If you continue to have problems, ask it as a separate question and reference this question/answer.

Answer (score 19):

The easiest way in EF6 To have the query always handy, without changing code is to add this to your DbContext and then just check the query on the output window in visual studio, while debugging.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    Database.Log = (query)=> Debug.Write(query);
}
```

**EDIT**

for EF Core the equivalent would be:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
```

as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/

Comment: I can't speak for EF6 but this does not seem to work in the new EF Core.

Comment: See: Entity Framework Logging and Intercepting Database Operations (EF6 Onwards) here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 13):

There is no equivalent of the `query.ToString()` AFAIK. You can eventually use [`DbContext.Database.Log`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.log(v=vs.113).aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.Database.Log) property:

```
db.Database.Log = s =>
{
    // You can put a breakpoint here and examine s with the TextVisualizer
    // Note that only some of the s values are SQL statements
    Debug.Print(s);
};
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Error CS1656: Cannot assign to 'Log' because it is a 'method group'

Answer (score 9):

use Interceptors for detail see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx)

> add this in to .config file

```
<interceptors> 
  <interceptor type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DatabaseLogger, EntityFramework"> 
    <parameters> 
      <parameter value="C:\Temp\LogOutput.txt"/> 
    </parameters> 
  </interceptor> 
</interceptors>
```

Comment: Won't this only log after the actual database operation is performed, i.e. after I call SaveChanges?

Comment: yes AFAIK for more information you can see this link http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Infrastructure/Interception/DatabaseLogger.cs and override the >IDbConfigurationInterceptor for your custom logging

Comment: My question is specifically about seeing the SQL before it is executed.

Comment: i don't know when it writes to file but you can check this at this method WriteThreadSafe in the given link that when it actually writes