# All data is not inserted in MySql instance using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Using a MariaDb instance database (fork of MySql) and using Entity Framework Core, give me a problem I've never experienced before, hence this post as I have no idea what is going on, and hoping that some of you guys might've experienced this before.

**Problem**

Take the following scenario. We have a table that look like this

```
News
-------------------------------------
| Id          | int      | not null |
| Title       | text     | not null |
| Content     | longtext | not null |
| Base64Image | blob     | null     |
-------------------------------------
```

Using C#, as my web application is build in ASP.NET Core MVC, I create a new instance of `News` object, just like so:

```
public IActionResult New (NewsViewModel model)
{
    using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        var news = new News()
        {
            Title = model.Title,
            Content = model.Content
        };

        db.News.Add(news);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Exactly as I'm used to from regular ASP.NET MVC applications, and I'd expect this to work just fine. Here's the catch though.

Viewing the data within my data visualizer (using HeidiSQL in this case) I can see that the string `Content` is shortened. I thought that this might just be a settings in HeidiSQL to not show the full string but only `x` amount of characters. Now, if I pull this entry back out from the database, I can see that the string IS actually only `x` amount of characters long, where as my initial string might be `x * 5`.

This gives me several problems, as the `Content` string is shortened, but also if the user uploads an image that I might want to convert to a base64 string. These strings tend to be long (depending on the data of course) and this will ALSO get shortened.

As mentioned in the very beginning of this post: I have absolutely no idea what is going on. I've never encountered this strange issue before, and I can't seem to google my way to a solution.

Can anyone lend a hand and explain to me what is going on?

**Examples of string content**

*Before saving to db (actual string I want to save, entered in a textarea frontend)* **490 characters**

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne per virtute insolens menandri, in cum utamur diceret menandri, fastidii petentium explicari et cum. Ex saperet definiebas quaerendum pri. Ei sed alii alterum alienum, mei graeco meliore pertinax eu, nec cu propriae molestie. Id eum zril timeam, at error gloriatur consectetuer est, et vim ceteros assueverit. At pri ancillae ponderum, ius an vidit dicant laudem. Ei usu corpora officiis principes, offendit percipitur eos et, qui ne consetetur concludaturque.

*After saving to the database (actual string as retrieved post save)* **252 characters**

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne per virtute insolens menandri, in cum utamur diceret menandri, fastidii petentium explicari et cum. Ex saperet definiebas quaerendum pri. Ei sed alii alterum alienum, mei graeco meliore pertinax eu, nec cu propriae molest

**EXTRA**

It looks like it's consistently around 235-260 characters that is actually saved to the database. Rest is just scrapped away. I've had several cases (238 characters, 243, 253, etc.)

**NEWS MODEL**

```
public class News
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Title", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.General))]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Content", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.General))]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "ThumbnailImage", Description = "NewsThumbnailImageDescription", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.General))]
    public string Base64ThumbnailImage { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "HeaderImage", Description = "NewsHeaderImageDescription", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.General))]
    public string Base64HeaderImage { get; set; }

    public string UserProfileUserName { get; set; }

    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

**DB TABLE**

[image]

Comment: Did you recently change the data type of the field in your database?

Comment: @RossBush I was thinking the same, potentially used to be TINYTEXT?

Comment: Can we see the entire 'News' model? There should be a generated class and possibly a partial.

Comment: Is it possible that your News model is defining a default maximum number of characters?

Comment: @RossBush I've changed between a few datatypes such as `BLOB`, `LONGTEXT`, and `TEXT`

Comment: @FrumRoll The datatype was never `TINYTEXT`, it has only been `BLOB`, `TEXT` and `LONGTEXT`

Comment: @NeilN I am not at my workstation for the next couple of hours, but I will get the `News` model up here when possible. It is not generated though, I made it myself.

Comment: @MedhatGayed I thought the same. I have no data annotation on my property, so if that's the problem, it has to set some default value somehow.

Comment: I think the first step is to check you column size, then once this is done, debug your Entity queries with, this thread will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36779057/entity-framework-6-how-can-i-view-the-sql-that-will-be-generated-for-an-insert

Comment: @pix Could you please explain what you mean by the column size? I'm not able to set a length for a `BLOB` datatype, am I? I've attached an image of my HeidiSql interface, showing the data type, and the length of the column.

Comment: Is this with the MySQL connector? This looks like a bug that we can't do much about. You could try with EF6 to make sure it's not an EF core issue (in combination with MariaDB).

Comment: @GertArnold Yes this is with the MySQL Connector (I believe it got released recently?)

Comment: Maybe is your front-end issue, check out you html code, make sure your form using `action = "post"`, and your action in controller should add `[HttpPost]` too. You can set a break point before `SaveChanges()`, check the `news.Content` if shortened, if true it's your front-end issue otherwise it's your DB or model.

Comment: @CodeFarmer Already did that. I found a solution though, will post as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TEMPORARY SOLUTION**

As it currently stands, the official `MySql.EntityFramework.Core` library for ASP.NET MVC Core is not working correctly, and this is a bug. After switching to a community version: `Pomelo.EntitytFramework.Core`, everything works like a charm. This one did it for me.

You can find the Pomelo repository [here](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql)

Comment: I can highly recommend the package from Pomelo. After switching to this package i could remove some workarounds I was forced to use.

Comment: I get a error with Pomelo (Asp.net Core Web Api application):
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void CoreTypeMappingParameters..ctor(System.Type, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, System.Func`3<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGenerator>)'....