# Entity Framework Core fails to rename database column

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, migration

Whenever I modify one of my entities and generate a migration using `Add-Migration <name>` in the Package Manager Console, if the generated `MigrationBuilder` contains a rename column operation such as:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
        name: "OldName",
        table: "MyTable",
        newName: "NewName");
}
```

then the `Update-Database` operation fails with the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Applying migration '20230506191317_mymigration'.
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MySQLMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(RenameColumnOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.<>c.<.cctor>b__82_22(MigrationsSqlGenerator g, MigrationOperation o, IModel m, MigrationCommandListBuilder b)
> at [...]
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)

It only happens when renaming columns. Removing that command from the migration and running the migration works. The `ModelSnapshot` is not out of sync.

I either have to nuke my migrations and start fresh or run the migration without the rename and manually rename the table in MySQL workbench.

I'm using .Net 7.0 and Entity Framework Core 7.0.5 with MySQL.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any seeding referring to this column? is the renaming command the only command in your migration?

Comment: @MernaMustafa no, nothing like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185832/all-data-is-not-inserted-in-mysql-instance-using-entity-framework-core) question that `MySql.EntityFramework.Core` has some issues, and to switch to [Pomelo](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql). I tried that, also specifying the right `MySqlServerVersion` version in the options when calling `UseMySql` and it now works. It also fixed other issues I was running into.